# Does Roland V-Drums Tutor work with other e-drums kits with midi output (ex. Millenium)

Tags: software, midi, electronic-drumset

I have a Millenium 150-E drums kit and I need a software for learning drums. Preferably with instant feedback on the note played, timing, etc.

I found the Roland V-Drums Tutor software but this was primarily designed for Roland V-Drums and I don't know if it works with my e-drums. Did anyone try to use this software with other e-drums than Roland's? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its [web site](https://www.roland.com/global/products/dt-1/specifications/) says:

> *Specifically designed for V-Drums; compatible with any Roland V-Drums kit.

That does not actually rule out other devices.

> Note number: corresponds to the pads of the V-Drums series
>   MIDI channel: 10

This appears to imply that any MIDI drum that sends these note numbers on channel 10 can be used.

> * A Roland V-Drums series drum set is required in order to use this software.

Uh oh.

> -V-Drums module without a USB COMPUTER port: A MIDI Interface and an audio cable are required.

When MIDI messages are received through a plain old MIDI cable (and there is no second MIDI cable in the other direction to send an inquiry to the device), the software has *no opportunity* to check which device it is connected to. So it should work.

Anyway, there is a [review](https://www.thomann.de/de/roland_dt_1_v_drum_tutor_reviews.htm?ar=276434&rating=5&reviewlang[]=1) (in German) that explicitly says that other MIDI sources work. (So the third quote above is a lie.)

Comment: Thanks. I could not (visibly) upvote your answer as I do not have enough reputation yet. But based on your answer I will risk 40$ to buy the Roland Tutor software and give it a try with my Millenium set. I will come back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably impossible.
The V-drum is connected with a computer via USB.

If your computer specialist and you are able to convert your midi output to a USB input. Than maybe it is possible.

Oh, I did not read the previous commend. Is there also v-drum without USB?
If so than maybe not impossible?

Comment: The Millenium 150-E has both USB out and MIDI out so it should work. However, I found another similar software which I think is better maintained and updated, it is called "Melodics" and works very well out of the box with the Millenium 150-E drum kit and with any other electronic drum kit. I use Melodics with USB connection. Thanks.